# C# How to send NUMPAD Keys to active application

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I have a global hotkey and it gets key regardless active application.
To be more precise it gets key from anywhere if it is activated. Besides it sends keys to the active application. But with `SendKey()` I can not send `NUMPAD0` - `NUMPAD9`
I have tried

```
void texbox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        SendKeys.Send("{NUMPAD7}");
}
```

But there is an error

```
Keyword "NUMPAD7" is not valid.
```

Any ideas??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us your error and also more than one row of code

Comment: void texbox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {if e.KeyCode==Keys.Space) SendKeys.Send("{NUMPAD7}");}

Comment: Error: "Keyword "NUMPAD7" is not valid." Sorry it is first time I am ever asking question

Comment: I added your code and error text to question, please review and accept if all right, or edit question yourself

Comment: You should add the code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found it. AUTOIT is the simplest solution for this. [https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit). Try this

```
AutoItX3 auto = new AutoItX3();
void texbox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        auto.Send("{NUMPAD7}");
}
```